# Custom Collector for Collectors.groupingBy doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Consider the simple class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo {

    public Float v1;
    public Float v2;
    public String name;

    public Foo(String name, Float v1, Float v2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.v2 = v2;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Now, I have a collection of `Foo`s and I'd like to group them by `Foo::getName`. I wrote a custom Collector to do that but it doesn't seem to work as expected. More precisely, `combiner()` never gets called. Why?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
        foos.add(new Foo("blue", 2f, 2f));
        foos.add(new Foo("blue", 2f, 3f));
        foos.add(new Foo("green", 3f, 4f));

        Map<String, Float> fooGroups = foos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getName, new FooCollector()));
        System.out.println(fooGroups);
    }

    private static class FooCollector implements Collector<Foo, Float, Float> {

        @Override
        public Supplier<Float> supplier() {
            return () -> new Float(0);
        }

        @Override
        public BiConsumer<Float, Foo> accumulator() {
            return (v, foo) -> v += foo.v1 * foo.v2;
        }

        @Override
        public BinaryOperator<Float> combiner() {
            return (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2;
        }

        @Override
        public Function<Float, Float> finisher() {
            return Function.identity();
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
            Set<Characteristics> characteristics = new TreeSet<>();
            return characteristics;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the input stream isn't parallel.

Comment: FYI, [`Collector.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) might be a more concise way to declare your collector.

Comment: Did you get two zeros instead of 10 and 12?

Comment: @rgettman, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the combiner function does not need to get called if you aren't using multiple threads (parallel stream).  The combiner gets called to combine the results of the operation on chunks of your stream.  There is no parallelism here so the combiner doesn't need to be called.

You are getting zero values because of your accumulator function.  The expression

```
v += foo.v1 * foo.v2;
```

will *replace* `v` with a new `Float` object.  The original accumulator object is not modified; it is still `0f`.  Besides, `Float`, like other numeric wrapper types (and `String`) is immutable and cannot be changed.

You need some other kind of accumulator object that is mutable.

```
class FloatAcc {
    private Float total;
    public FloatAcc(Float initial) {
        total = initial;
    }
    public void accumulate(Float item) {
        total += item;
    }
    public Float get() {
        return total;
    }
}
```

Then you can modify your custom `Collector` to use `FloatAcc`.  Supply a new `FloatAcc`, call `accumulate` in the `accumulator` function, etc.

```
class FooCollector implements Collector<Foo, FloatAcc, Float> {
    @Override
    public Supplier<FloatAcc> supplier() {
        return () -> new FloatAcc(0f);
    }
    @Override
    public BiConsumer<FloatAcc, Foo> accumulator() {
        return (v, foo) -> v.accumulate(foo.v1 * foo.v2);
    }
    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<FloatAcc> combiner() {
        return (v1, v2) -> {
            v1.accumulate(v2.get());
            return v1;
        };
    }
    @Override
    public Function<FloatAcc, Float> finisher() {
        return FloatAcc::get;
    }
    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        Set<Characteristics> characteristics = new TreeSet<>();
        return characteristics;
    }
}
```

With these changes I get what you're expecting:

```
{green=12.0, blue=10.0}
```

Comment: Isn't it also significant that the stream is small? So, even if it were a parallel stream, the 3 elements would just be processed as if they were a sequential stream, because the overhead of processing 3 things in parallel isn't worth it.

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't know the internal details about how parallel streams actually decide to parallelize, but that sounds reasonable.

Comment: Yeah, actually I'll go with that! Much more neat and simple!

Comment: @AndyTurner when you request parallel, you get parallel, regardless of whether it is worth it. The Stream API can’t decide beforehand whether the per-element processing costs will justify the parallel processing. So even an `ArrayList` with two elements can be processed in parallel, using the combiner. The only exception would be if the first thread truly processed the first element so fast, that it could steal back the workload of the second before it could pick it up. Then, it’s implementation specific whether it will use the combiner.

Comment: @rgettman there is no reason for `FloatAcc` to use `Float` instead of `float`. That destroys the entire benefit of using `collect` instead of `reduce`. So it should use `float`, or you replace the entire class by a single element `float[]` array, as the built-in collectors do internally. Speaking of built-in collectors, `collectingAndThen(summingDouble(foo -> foo.v1 * foo.v2), d -> (float)d)` would do.

Comment: While this solution is correct and answers the question based on the OP's terms, I think it's also totally overkill. There's no need for a custom collector here, and even less for a mutable accumulator class.

Answer (score 3):

You have an explanation as to why the current collector does not work from [rgettman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54657361/3788176).

It is worth checking to see what helper methods exist to create custom collectors. For example, this entire collector can be defined far more concisely as:

```
reducing(0.f, v -> v.v1 * v.v2, (a, b) -> a + b)
```

It is not always possible to use methods like these; but the conciseness (and, presumably, the well-testedness) should make them the first choice when possible.

Comment: When the groups have a lot of elements, it’s worth avoiding the boxing overhead using `collectingAndThen(summingDouble(foo -> foo.v1 * foo.v2), d -> (float)d)` instead.

Comment: @Holger I'd even avoid using `collectingAndThen`. Just `summingDouble(foo -> foo.v1 * foo.v2)` would do it, and if OP really wants a `float` instead of a `double`, a simple cast would do it. (But I admit it is a matter of taste and coding style, i.e. totally subjective).

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner the OP uses this collector as downstream collector of a `groupingBy`, to get a `Map<String, Float>`, so in this specific case, you need the `collectingAndThen` (unless switching to `Map<String, Double>` is an option).

Comment: @Holger Good point. I've overlooked that OP was using this as a downstream collector.